# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'apps.ika.gr'

Tags: c#, security, ssl, channel

visual studio 2019 
c#

There was an error downloading 'https://apps.ika.gr/eServiceRadioTherapy-eServiceRadioTherapyWS-context-root/Port?WSDL/$metadata'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://apps.ika.gr/eServiceRadioTherapy-eServiceRadioTherapyWS-context-root/Port?WSDL'.
Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'apps.ika.gr'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: Windows 10, version 1903.

Comment: visual studio >Add > Service Reference

Answer (score 0):

i had to install apps.ika certificate to 
local Computer (Not user account) > Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Answer (score 0):

create a user in service with **same name** of one *system* user
like: administrator
this is not real system session its fake but some services in ***security softwares*** has this trick, *try this...*